# Rapid increase of battery wear level in Acer V3-571G - more than twice in two weeks

Tags: laptop, battery, acer-aspire

I use HWINFO64 to get information about notebook's components. There is information about battery wear level. It is a percent of battery capacity which have been lost:

```
batteryWear = 100% - (currentMaximumCapacity/originalMaximumCapacity) * 100%
```

Two weeks ago that was just 35 percent. Today 6 hours ago it was 66%, now it is 74.7%. I got 71% of battery left and 27 minutes left to work on it.

```
Device Name:                              Li_Ion_4000mA 
Manufacturer Name:                        LG 
Serial Number:                            AAFF
Unique ID:                                AAFFLG Li_Ion_4000mA 
Chemistry:                                                                      
Designed Capacity:                        47520 mWh
Full Charged Capacity:                    12042 mWh
Wear Level:                               74.7 %
Power Status:                             Discharging 
Current Capacity:                         4817 mWh (40.0 %)
Current Voltage:                          10.887 V
Discharge Rate:                           -18911 mW
```

It is exacly one month and 10 days till 2 years passing from buying this notebook.(bought 16-10-2012).

Can I fix it somehow using software tools? Is it just manufacturer forcing me to buy new notebook? Is it going to blow up?

Answer (score 2):

I work in IT and it looks like your battery is just really worn out and needs to be replaced with a fresh battery. Acer typical uses battery cells that only last about 2 years.

In my office we usually replace the batteries once the get to 50% wear.  Any more than that and the batteries won't last a short meeting in a conference room.

Not sure if your battery is internal or external, but either can be replaced. External batteries are obliviously a no brainer.

My office start buying replacement battery that use some very fancy cells desgined to last over 3 years (800-900 charging cycles) and provide more run time than OEM and it has worked well and would recommend them for their quality if you decide to get a replacement battery.

SafeBatteries.com

-Bart